# Can we store integers in less than 4 bytes?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, int, byte

I understand that using a `short` in Java we can store a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive).
And using an `int` we can store  a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1
Question: If I have an `int[] numbers` and the numbers I can store are positive up to 10Million.
Is it possible to somehow store these numbers without having to use 4 bytes for each? I am wondering if for a specific "small" range there might be some "hack/trick" so that I could use less memory than `numbers.length*4`

Comment: What is the "small range" you are talking about?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @CrApHer:Only numbers from 0 up to 10Million (mention it in the OP)

Comment: @AlexFItzpatrick:Yes I know. I was wondering if there was some "trick" eg using bit or something if we don't generally care about integers but only in a specific "small" range

Comment: 2^24 is 16,777,216.  So, you can store your values in 24 bits.  If your "small" range is less than 10 million, you might be able to use fewer bits.  I hope that this is a learning exercise, and not some hack for a production system.

Comment: Yes, but how are the number distributed?  Are they mostly small (<32,000) or do you have a lot of number which are greater than that?  If the latter, you probably won't be able to compress storage much.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, there are *many* possible ways to store data with reqducing space requirement, but to sensibly select between different storage schemes such as custom-bit-length words, actual data compression (lossy or lossless) one needs to carefully consider what properties are actually desired (such as access pattern, random or sequential) and where to make the tradeoff between *space* and *time* complexity.

Comment: @markspace:Mostly less than 1million

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc:Well if there is an actual optimization why not use it in production?

Comment: @Durandal:You have a point. But since it is about an operation involving a primitive type in-memory I would only be interested in a space improvement without any time overhead (that is more than O(1))

Comment: @Jim I have some compression routines for integers, but they're designed for even smaller numbers, mostly less than 100.  One million is 0xF4240 hex and needs three bytes minimum to store.  You won't see a lot of compression.  I can't see this being worth while.

Comment: If you actually want to do this, keep in mind that you could get a significant slow down. The hardware likes things to be aligned on word, double word, and quad word boundaries (16 through 64 bits on intel, including 128-bit and 256-bit alignment for memory loaded into XMM/YMM registers), including data that doesn't straddle a cache line.  It's why languages typically don't have like a 24-bit integer. They're made to reflect what efficiently maps to hardware.

Comment: Typically, unless you just need a boatload of numbers and space is more of a concern than time, you'll do better if you need a 24-bit integer to store a 32-bit one and find some other use for the extra 8 bits. That keeps the data aligned, doesn't straddle cache lines for a single field, and gives you some extra bits to work with to store auxiliary data.

Comment: If you want some idea of the slowdowns, I tried this same thing before in C++ with some optimism, and found it was approx 30 times slower when the data was aligned all funky and no longer on 32-bit/64-bit boundaries. YMMV but the hardware really likes these things to be aligned, so it's best to think of this like a compression scheme to compress and decompress big chunks to process, not like a one-to-one exchange of a lower-sized int to be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Jim: Because your compression code is more likely to have mistakes than the Java code to manipulate ints.  Don't create unnecessary problems.

Comment: @Ike What you describe is a non-problem.  One would typically use a `long[]` for doing this and this means one needs to read at most 2 consecutive (and, of course, well aligned) `long`  values.

Comment: @Ingo Yes, but that's a packing problem where you become tuned to the alignment. If you treat it as a compression strategy, it works fine. If you use it like a way to directly fetch any arbitrary entry from it with random access, that's where you get those alignment problems. So it can work quite well if you are aware of the alignment, still work in byte-sized multiples, and pack and unpack multiple of these at a time rather than one at a time.

Comment: Where I went wrong was trying to treat it like a general-purpose array of integers with any arbitrary bit-size, including funky ones like 5-bit integers that cannot possibly align in any combination to a word/dword/qword boundary. If you do it with a sensitivity towards alignment, like noting that  how many integers align to a qword 64-bit boundary and work with all at one time, and inserting some padding to help things align, this might work quite well. Ex: 6 5-bit integers (30 bits) followed by 2-bit padding for alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to use a smaller number of bits by using masking or bit-operations to represent each number, and then perform a sign-extension later on if you wish to get the full number of bits. This kind of operation is done on a system-architecture level in nearly all computer systems today.

It may help you to research [**2's Complement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which seems to be what you are going for...  And possibly [Sign Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) for good measure.

Typically, in high-level languages an int is represented by the basic size of the processor register. ex) 8, 16, 32, or 64-bits.

If you use a 2's-Complement method, you could easily account for the full spectrum of positive and negative numbers if needed. This is also very easy on the hardware, because you only have to invert all the bits and then add 1, which may prove to give you a big performance increase over other possible methods.

---

**How 2's Complement Works**:

- Get –N by inversing all bits and then
  add 1

That is, get 1-complement of N and then add 1 to it.

```
For example with 8-bit words:
 9 = 00001001
-9 = 11110111 (11110110 + 1)
```

Easily and efficiently in hardware
(inverse and then +1)
• An n-bit word can be used to represent numbers
from -2^(N-1) to +(2^(N-1) - 1)

---

**UPDATE**: Bit-operations to represent larger numbers.

If you are trying to get a larger number, say 1,000,000 as in your comment, then you can use a Bitwise left-shift operation to then extract the number by increasing your current number by the appropriate power of 2.

```
    9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
                  --------------------------------
9 << 2 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000100100 (base 2) = 36 (base 10)
```

You could also try:
**([Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators))**

This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.

For non-negative numbers, zero-fill right shift and sign-propagating right shift yield the same result. For example, `9 >>> 2 yields 2`, the same as `9 >> 2`:

```
9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
9 >>> 2 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000000010 (base 2) = 2 (base 10)
```

However, this is not the case for negative numbers. For example, `-9 >>> 2 yields 1073741821`, which is different than `-9 >> 2` (which yields -3):

```
-9 (base 10): 11111111111111111111111111110111 (base 2)
                    --------------------------------
-9 >>> 2 (base 10): 00111111111111111111111111111101 (base 2) = 1073741821 (base 10)
```

---

As others have stated in the comments, you could actually hamper your overall performance in the long-run if you are attempting to manipulate data that is not specifically word/double/etc-aligned. This is because your hardware will have to work a bit harder to try and piece together what you truly need.

Comment: It depends on how many such items need to get stored.  If you can save 10 bits and have to keep 1 billion numbers, you save more than a gigabyte.

Comment: @Ingo Good point, I removed that statement in my post and updated :)

Comment: And I will always be able to get back the number "uniquely"?

Comment: @Jim yes, as long as you follow the 2's Complement rule. Each number has a completely unique binary representation.

Comment: Is this encoding/decoding too much of an overhead? Or is it considered like `O(1)`?

Comment: It is constant time, I believe. It really depends on how you implement it in the end.

Bitwise operations are extremely quick and if you never use subtraction the hardware will be able to do each operation in 1 clock cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your example but how will this help in representing a number that is over 1 million? (i.e. exceeds 2 bytes normally)

Comment: The formula you wrote is to the power?

Comment: You could use the Bitwise AND operation to mask bits and then extend to represent the larger number :) @Jim yes it's to the power.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. If I do the masking won't the bits be cleared and the original number lost? Could you please show 1 example?

Comment: @Jim Ok, I provided a couple examples and a link demonstrating further uses.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use bit manipulation and use a number of bits of your choosing to store a single number. Say you select to use 5 bits. You can then store 4 such numbers in 4 bytes. You need to pack and unpack the bits into an integer when operations need to be done.

You need to decide if you want to deal with negative numbers in which case you need to store a sign bit.

To make it easier to use, you need to create a class that will conceal the nitty-gritty details via get and store operations.

In light of the questions about performance, as is often the case, we are trading space for performance or vise versa. Depending on the situation various optimization techniques can be used to minimize the number of CPU cycles.

That said, is there a need for such optimization in the first place? If so, is it at the memory level or storage level? Could we use a generic mechanism such as compression to take care of this instead of using special techniques?

Comment: No, not a sign bit. Use 2's complement.

Comment: @Ingo Sure, that will avoid dealing with 0 and -0 and increase the range by 1.

Comment: @Tarik a penny saved is a penny earned!

Comment: @Tarik A penny saved is two pennies earned. You forgot the tax.

Comment: No negative numbers. But how will  I get back the original number? Is it not possible 2 different numbers to have the same bit pattern in these 5 selected bits?

Comment: With 5 bits you have a range from 0 to 2^5-1 (0 to 31) unsigned integers. You need to do some reading about binary representation of numbers.

Comment: @Jim Don't bother with bits. When you need non-negative numbers up to 10e6, it fits perfectly in 3 bytes. This is simpler and faster that the general case. *However, most of the time, buying more memory is the cheapest solution.*

Answer (score 1):

Just another thought. One parameter is the range of numbers you have. But also other properties can help save storage. For example, when you know that each number will be divisible by some multiple of 8, you need not store the lower 3 bits, since you know they are 0 all the time. (This is how the JVM stores "compressed" references.)

Or, to take another possible scenario: When you store prime numbers, then all of them (except 2) will be odd. So no need to store the lowest bit, as it is always 1. Of course you need to handle 2 separately. A similar trick is used in floating point representations: since the first bit of the mantissa of a non-null number is always 1, it is not stored at all, thus increasing precision by 1 bit.

Comment: Very interesting but there is no such property